# How to set up a Private network and connect peers in geth?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, peer, local-network, private-network

I am trying to setup a private network and trying to connect peers. Currently I'm trying it on my laptop and desktop (both of them are connected to different internet).

I run the below command in first terminal(in both systems (`data dir` is different in both systems)):

```
geth --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "http://localhost:5000, http://localhost:6000" --port "2403" --ipcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --networkid 1001201 --datadir "E:\User\priv\data" init "E:\User\priv\genesis.json"
```

then I run:

```
geth --datadir "E:\User\priv\data"
```

Now, in the second terminal:

```
geth attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth.ipc
```

I get the **same enode** value on both the systems when i run `admin.nodeInfo.enode`

then on 1st PC,

```
admin.addPeer("enode://e0c4960659b6ce4eda71c67b337055636f67660a711d157a81572b5eff1ed1b77931bef4bd079e2660baa661ac16d696b831e9394cb619378071a2593ecdf17a@[192.168.1.2]:30301");
```

on 2nd PC,

```
admin.addPeer("enode://e0c4960659b6ce4eda71c67b337055636f67660a711d157a81572b5eff1ed1b77931bef4bd079e2660baa661ac16d696b831e9394cb619378071a2593ecdf17a@[13.75.117.156]:30302");
```

both of them return `true`.
But `admin.peerCount` returns `0`.

Can somebody please help me to setup a private geth network?

Answer (score 2):

**Step1**

```
geth --identity "YourNodeName" --rpc --rpcport "8092" --datadir "DirectoryPathToStoreData" --port "30330" --nodiscover --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --networkid 2010 init PathOfGenesisFile
```

The above command is to initialise a Genesis File.

Note: All Peers willing to connect to a network should have  a same Genesis File.

**Step2**

```
geth --identity "YourNodeName" --rpc --rpcport "8092" --datadir "DirectoryPathToStoreData" --port "30330" --nodiscover --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --networkid 2010 console
```

The above command opens a Geth JavaScript console.
Do the above 2 steps in other system also.

**Step3**

In the system where you want to add other system as peer type the following command `admin.addPeer("Argument")` where Argument is the enode value of other node which is obtained by typing `admin.nodeInfo()` in other system.

```
Eg:admin.nodeInfo
{
  enode: "enode://965dc2b0f39e199d3a07871293015d8a4ad9349834fc27b7ee5e87bea89547e4fafda3ce7982ae07c14b8770c87a6c14e3fe2f91ef0d0ca717eb6ae56aa3e74b@[::]:30330?discport=0",
  //////////
}
```

where `30330` is the network id of other system.

copy upto `30330`.You need to give the ip address of other system in place of

```
[::]
```

It returns true if that node is capable of acting as a peer but not mean that it is added to our network, to know that `type net.peerCount`. It returns 1, if added.

You can follow the step3 for adding more peers.

You can create a private blockchain without creating a Genesis File.If you opt for that, follow [this link](https://medium.com/enpit-developer-blog/getting-started-with-ethereum-blockchain-and-smart-contract-development-a1ae41c01105).

Comment: I have set up my private net, but I when I start geth is starts interchanging discovery traffic with other IPs that I know nothing about. This traffic is very heavy and is saturating my network. Do you know how to setup the discovery only for the nodes that belong to my own network?

Comment: you can add --nodiscover protocal when you initiate a genesis file for your network

Comment: but if I use nodiscover how do I find other users that are connecting to my private network?

Comment: you need to add others either at run time or include their enodes/pubkeys in static-nodes.json file in geth folder

Comment: well it wouldn't be possible, I wouldn't know the IP addresses of every user that downloads our client and connects to our private net

Answer (score 0):

As outlined [here](http://mahesh-developernotes.blogspot.co.uk/2017/03/ethereum-blockchain-private-setup-geth.html), your `--port` and `--rpcport` variables should be different. The resulting `EnodeURLs` should also be different.

Also, when you run geth the second time, I'd include everything you used in the first run before `init`.

Comment: No its not working. when i run net.peerCount, it returns 0.